# How to import an mbox file into evolution mail ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-10.10, evolution

How to import an mbox file into evolution mail ubuntu? I have a mbox file with size 2Gigs and I need to get it imported urgently into evolution. I've googled but still can't find any method. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+question/325

To import from an mbox file:

- Select File -> Import from the menu.
- You get "Evolution Import Assistant". Click Forward
- Select option "Import a single file"
- Click the Browse... button and find the mbox you want to import. Click OK
- It should detect it as "Berkeley Mailbox (mbox)". Click Forward
- Choose which mail folder you want the mbox imported into (Destination folder). Click Forward
- Click Import